# Defaulted destructor in base class disable move constructor in child class if there is a member

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics, virtual-destructor

Why does defaulted (*user declared*) destructor in `Base1` prevent generation of move constructor/operator in `Child1` class, but everything work fine when I move member `data` from Base (`Base2`) to Child (`Child2`) class?

```cpp
struct Data {
    Data() {}
    Data(Data&&) noexcept { cout << "Move constructor" << endl; }
    Data& operator=(Data&&) noexcept {
        cout << "Move assign" << endl;
        return *this;
    }
    vector<int> vec;
};

struct Base1 {
    virtual void fun() { cout << "Base1::fun" << endl; }
    virtual ~Base1() = default;
    Data data;
};

struct Child1 : public Base1 {
    void fun() override { cout << "Child1::fun" << endl; }
};

struct Base2 {
    virtual void fun() { cout << "Base2::fun" << endl; }
    virtual ~Base2() = default;
};

struct Child2 : public Base2 {
    void fun() override { cout << "Child2::fun" << endl; }
    Data data;
};

int main() {
    Child1 c1;
    auto obj1 = std::move(c1);  // error

    Child2 c2;
    auto obj2 = std::move(c2);
}
```

My current understanding is that when I declare destructor as “`default`” in Base (`BaseDel`), then move constructor should be “`deleted`” in Base (`BaseDel`) and in Child (`ChildDel`) class. Is this correct? Member location shouldn’t matter, I think. If I do that explicit, I get expected error:

```cpp
struct BaseDel {
    BaseDel() {}
    virtual void fun() { cout << "BaseDel::fun" << endl; }
    BaseDel(BaseDel&& st) = delete;
    virtual ~BaseDel() = default;
};

struct ChildDel : public BaseDel {
    ChildDel() {}
    void fun() override { cout << "ChildDel::fun" << endl; }
    Data data;
};

int main() {
    ChildDel cd;
    auto objd = std::move(cd);  // OK, expected error
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The implicit move constructor is not (only) *deleted*, it is not *declared* in the first place when you have a user-declared destructor, as is the case with `Base1` and `Base2`.

Therefore the move constructor can never be considered in overload resolution and so `auto obj1 = std::move(c1);`, while it can call `Child1`'s move constructor, needs to fall back to copy construction for the `Base1` subobject.

The implicitly-declared copy constructors of both `Base1` and `Child1` are defined as deleted, because `Data`'s implicitly-declared copy constructor is defined as deleted, because `Data` has a user-defined move constructor. Therefore `auto obj1 = std::move(c1);` will fail with an error that the implicitly-declared copy constructor is deleted.

For `Base2` the copy constructor is not defined as deleted, because it doesn't have a `Data` member and so `auto obj2 = std::move(c2);` will call `Child2`'s move constructor (which also uses `Data`'s move constructor), but use the *copy constructor* for the `Base2` subobject.

Comment: Hi @walnut. If _"The implicitly-declared copy constructors of both `Base1` and `Child1` are defined as deleted"_ … _"because `Data` has a user-defined move constructor"_ then why copy constructor is not deleted from `Child2`? If Data affects declaration of copy constructor in `Base1` it should in same way affect declaration in `Child2` (now this object store `data`). Isn't it? Then why _"`auto obj2 = std::move(c2);` will _copy_"_?

Comment: @NiegodziwyBeru Sorry, I made a mistake there. I have updated my answer. Only the `Base2` subobject is copied. The `Child2` object and its `Data` member are move constructed.

Comment: Ok, I think I finally understood. So user-declared destructor doesn’t delete any implicit-declared _mechanics_ like move constructor, in contrast to user-declared move constructor that delete implicit-declared copy constructor.